# "This Field is Required" error even after sending the fields

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
class DroneList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Drone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DroneSerializer
    name = 'drone-list'
    filter_fields = (
        'name',
        'drone_category',
        'manufacturing_date',
        'has_it_competed',
    )
    search_fields = (
        '^name',
    )
    ordering_fields = (
        'name',
        'manufacturing_date',
    )
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner = self.request.user)
```

Views.py

```
class DroneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
# Display the category name
drone_category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=DroneCategory.objects.all(),
                                              slug_field='name')

owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

class Meta:
    model = Drone
    fields = (
        'url',
        'name',
        'drone_category',
        'manufacturing_date',
        'has_it_competed',
        'inserted_timestamp',
        'owner'
    )


class UserDroneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Drone
         fields = (
            'url',
            'name')
```

Serializer.py

```
class DroneCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Drone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    drone_category = models.ForeignKey(
        DroneCategory,
       related_name='drones',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturing_date = models.DateTimeField()
    has_it_competed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       owner = models.ForeignKey(
       'auth.User',
       related_name='drones',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models.py

{"name":"Python Drone", 
    "drone_category":"Quadcopter", "manufacturing_date": "2017-07-
     16T02:03:00.716312Z", "has_it_competed": "false"}

Post request I had send.

the fields are not read by django as shown in the response:
"name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "drone_category": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "manufacturing_date": [
        "This field is required."
    ]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
class UserDroneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Drone
         fields = (
            'url',
            'name',
        'drone_category',
        'manufacturing_date',
        'has_it_competed',
        'inserted_timestamp',
        'owner')
```

Comment: Still Giving me the same message

Comment: can you add your form by which you post data or json?

Comment: I am using postman/curl for this.
curl --user "user01":"user01password" -iX POST -H "Content-
    Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Python Drone", 
    "drone_category":"Quadcopter", "manufacturing_date": "2017-07-
     16T02:03:00.716312Z", "has_it_competed": "false"}' localhost:8000/drones/

Comment: Yes I did.It gave another field error that is owner

Comment: I can't get the other fields to works apart from owner

Comment: '{"name":"Python Drone", "drone_category":"Quadcopter", "manufacturing_date": "2017-07- 16T02:03:00.716312Z", "has_it_competed": "false", "owner": 1}'

Comment: Thanks that did for me